# What is the IAR equivalent of __attribute__(section)

Tags: gnu-make, gnu, ld, iar

Can I directly use the `__attribute__((section))` directly as I did in arm gcc or is there any equivalent for the same.. My code has functions utilizing the above construct (which is defined through macro)..

```
#define PLACE_IN_REGION1 __attribute((section(".section1")))

void function( int ) PLACE_IN_REGION1;
```

If a similar equivalent is present, I could replace the same without any hassle..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location` pragma, in preprocessor macro form:

```
#define PLACE_IN_REGION1 _Pragma("location=\"section1\"")   // section1 is region you have defined in the linker file
PLACE_IN_REGION1 void function(int);
```

Only difference is that it needs to be at the beginning of the declaration, so you'll need to edit your code a bit.